# JavaScript Functions Doesn't Work For Me

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Even this simple one doesn't seem to work and I have no earthly idea why. 
I'm trying to remove that class, but it doesn't really matter, because whatever I'm trying to do it's not working. I would like to know why.

Here's my css:

```
          <i onclick="removeClass()" class="fas fa-bars slide"></i>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
                 function removeClass() {
                 var icon = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
                 element.classList.remove("fa-bars");
                 }
```

Comment: Where is `removeClass` method defined?

Comment: Oh, that's a mistake here. It's defined in my code.

Comment: Where is `element` defined?

Comment: That might be why it's not working. Thank you. I'm pretty new to JavaScript.

Comment: You might mean `this` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to remove one of the classes from the element,

Pick the element - There are multiple ways to do this,

- Document.getElementsByClassName()
- Document.getElementsByTagName()
- document.getElementById(String id)
- document.getElementsByName()

Using getElementById() will pick out a very specific element,

> ```
> <i id="italics-slider" onclick="removeClass()" class="fas fa-bars slide"></i>
> ```

```
function removeClass() {
   var icon = document.getElementById("italics-slider");
   icon.classList.remove("fa-bars");
}
```

Comment: The class is not getting removed. Whether I use inline or a linked js file. I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<i id="slide" onClick="removeClass(this)" class="fas fa-bars slide">X</i>
```

JavaScript

```
function removeClass(element) {
  element.classList.remove('slide')
}
```